# web3 get_transaction get_transaction_receipt how to see the error-Message for a failed transaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, web3.py

I am using the web3-implementation from python (web3.py) and use the both methods *get_transaction* and *get_transaction_receipt* to lookup failed transactions. If the status-field from *get_transaction_receipt* is 0, i know the transaction has failed.

But if i lookup the transaction with etherscan (or bscscan) i see an error-message (for example: "Fail with error 'Return amount is not enough'".

How can i lookup the transaction with web3 to get access to the content of the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the current scenario, web3.py doesn't handle this very well, this due to differnt clients handle RPC response in differnt ways (see this [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1888)). However, this is being worked upon very actively (see this [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1941)).

There are few workarounds to accomplish this:

- use [eth-brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#brownie.network.transaction.TransactionReceipt), `TransactionReceipt.revert_msg` will give the verbose message for revert and `TransactionReceipt.dev_revert_msg` allows customization for developer specified revert comment
- use raw RPC call and parse the json

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Tenderly API to do it, here is a sample:

GET [https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/{chainId}/tx/{txHash}](https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/%7BchainId%7D/tx/%7BtxHash%7D)

Set the chain id and transaction hash in the request path.

By calling this API, you could check the failure reason in the `error_message` field or in the `stack_trace[i].error`

Here is a sample failed transaction:

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2

As it is polygon and polygon chain id is 137, you could call this API like this:

```
curl 'https://api.tenderly.co/api/v1/public-contract/137/tx/0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2' \
      -H 'authority: api.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
      -H 'accept-language: fa,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.7' \
      -H 'origin: https://dashboard.tenderly.co' \
      -H 'referer: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/' \
       --compressed
```

This is the API response:

```
{
  "hash": "0x7473494c4d6ac6976193f67e624dbd0963a321dc883ea8d90e115f5246a3b6d2",
  "error_message": "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance",
  ...
}
```

Comment: FYI this answer was flagged as a duplicate.